# How I can make icon in href?

Tags: html, css

I wrote this code

```
<a href="trans.php"> here </a>
```

How I can make `icon` as `picture` instead of `here` .
I want when I run this code appears as icon when I click on this icon direct me to trans.php .

Comment: http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

enclose an image tag within the `<a>` tag.
like,

```
<a href='trans.php'><img src='pic.jpg'/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use image `<img src="" alt="" />` as icon

or

try to implement and use **Font Awesome Icons** https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Answer (score 1):

There is another way if you don't want to use image tag is glyphicons`

for example

this example is taken from bootstrap there is a file which contain icons u just need to add this in your file

```
 <a href='trans.php'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>
```